# Excel VBA macro dir() function incorrect return value when folder is empty

Tags: excel, vba, function, directory

Trying to use the DIR function in a Macro to determine whether a folder exists. Have found the following code

```
Function FileOrFolderExistsOnMac(FileOrFolderstr As String) As Boolean
Ron de Bruin : 1-Feb-2019
Function to test whether a file or folder exist on a Mac in office 2011 and up
'Uses AppleScript to avoid the problem with long names in Office 2011,
'limit is max 32 characters including the extension in 2011.
    Dim ScriptToCheckFileFolder As String
    Dim TestStr As String

    If Val(Application.Version) < 15 Then
        ScriptToCheckFileFolder = "tell application " & Chr(34) & "System Events" & Chr(34) & _
         "to return exists disk item (" & Chr(34) & FileOrFolderstr & Chr(34) & " as string)"
        FileOrFolderExistsOnMac = MacScript(ScriptToCheckFileFolder)
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        TestStr = Dir(FileOrFolderstr & "*", vbDirectory)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not TestStr = vbNullString Then FileOrFolderExistsOnMac = True
    End If
End Function
```

from
https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm

However, when the folder in the path location is empty, the function determines that the path directory does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the post, it helped me identify the source of my problem.

I modified my often-used function to account for this quirk.

Here's a modified function that should work for empty folders (works on Windows, not tested on Macs).

```
Function directoryExists(ByVal dirPath As String) As Boolean
    'amy@logicallytech.com
    '7/15/2022
    
    directoryExists = (Dir(dirPath) <> "")
    If directoryExists Then Exit Function
    
    'If folder is empty, above will show it does not exist, so just to confirm...
    Dim strParentFolder As String
    Dim strSubFolder As String
    Dim myfso As Object
    Dim parentFolder As Object
    Dim subFolder As Object
    
    If InStr(dirPath, "\") > 0 Then
        If Right(dirPath, 1) = "\" Then dirPath = Left(dirPath, Len(dirPath) - 1)
        strParentFolder = Left(dirPath, InStrRev(dirPath, "\", , vbTextCompare))
        strSubFolder = Right(dirPath, Len(dirPath) - InStrRev(dirPath, "\", , vbTextCompare))
    ElseIf InStr(dirPath, "/") > 0 Then
        If Right(dirPath, 1) = "/" Then dirPath = Left(dirPath, Len(dirPath) - 1)
        strParentFolder = Left(dirPath, InStrRev(dirPath, "/", , vbTextCompare))
        strSubFolder = Right(dirPath, Len(dirPath) - InStrRev(dirPath, "/", , vbTextCompare))
    End If
    
    Set myfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set parentFolder = myfso.GetFolder(strParentFolder)
    For Each subFolder In parentFolder.SubFolders
        If LCase(Trim(subFolder.Name)) = LCase(Trim(strSubFolder)) Then
            directoryExists = True
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If
    Next subFolder
    
CleanUp:
    Set subFolder = Nothing
    Set parentFolder = Nothing
    Set myfso = Nothing
End Function
```